# javascript can not use import in chrome firefox and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, web, firefox

I have those 3 files:

index.html

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

sayHi.js

```
function sayHi(user) {
    alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}
export {sayHi}; // a list of exported variables
```

main.js

```
import {sayHi} from './say.js';
sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
```

Error node:

```
PS C:\Users\Roxanji\VScode\test4> node .\main.js
C:\Users\Roxanji\VScode\test4\main.js:2
import {sayHi} from './say.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Error in chrome:

```
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Roxanji/VScode/test4/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
index.html:1 GET file:///C:/Users/Roxanji/VScode/test4/main.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Error in firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Roxanji/VScode/test4/main.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
2
Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///C:/Users/Roxanji/VScode/test4/main.js”.
```

Where it works:
parcel and liveserver(the one in visualcode)

How can I make it so that it works everywhere? especially in node?

Comment: I think ES6 supporting is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why modules do not work on node and browsers are two:

- Node: If you are using a version higher than 13 (if I'm not mistaken) you have to enter the field `type` valorized to `module` in the `package.json`.
  If you are using a previous version, you must use the --experimental-modules flag (I suggest you read the documentation https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html).
- Browser: The errors are explanatory enough: the page must be served on `http/s` protocol and not `file`. For this reason it works with liveserver but not by accessing the page directly